# Jquery UI Drag&Drop compatibility issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In this article, Marcos Placona, describes how to implement Jquery Drag&Drop with cloning. 
http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/

It works great with JQuery 1.3.x and JQuery UI 1.7.x but it's not working using JQuery 1.4+ and JQuery Ui 1.8+

Here a working JSFiddle example, can you help?
http://jsfiddle.net/trustweb/6h4N4/1/

Answer (score 0):

seems to be that theres a bug right now using backgroundimages as a clone.
If you insert some text into the .drag divs or style it with a border, you will see it works.
As you "just" using backgroundimages theres no visual feedback that you drag or drop something.

I guess its a bug. But im not sure, its a bug or feature that its not possible anymore to helper: clone, or helper: original with only bg-images.

Comment: if i put some text, i can drag once, but i cannot re-drag dropped items.